# log4j 2.2 issues after migrating from log4j 1.2.17

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have migrated from log4j 1.2.17 to log4j 2.2. and I'm getting the following issues:

1. My AsyncLogger is working like a sync one. This is my config for this logger:

   <RollingFile name="ACCESS_LOG" 
        fileName="${sys:log.dir}vproxy_access.${date:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                filePattern="${sys:log.dir}vproxy_access.${date:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                append="true" 
        bufferedIO="true"
        bufferSize="8192"
        immediateFlush="false">
    <PatternLayout>
      <Pattern>%m%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}%n
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies/>
   </RollingFile>

   <AsyncLogger name="LOGGER_ACCESS" level="info" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
     <AppenderRef ref="ACCESS_LOG"/>
   </AsyncLogger>

The log creation is correct but everything I log to this file is not buffered and the lines are committed immediately. I've been compared my config with others I've seen in other posts and I can't see what's wrong.

2. When I shutdown my application, now I'm getting the following error:

Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessageFactory.newMessage(ParameterizedMessageFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:737)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:708)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.error(AbstractLogger.java:314)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:77)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessage
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        ... 6 more

When this error appears I'm not logging anything. The last line I log is shown correctly in its corresponding log.

3. When logging to a file with a sync logger, strange characters occasionally appear. See below "^[[?1;2c^[[?1;2c" (this didn't happen with 1.2.17).

2015-04-02 13:58:51     Starting messaging service ...

^[[?1;2c^[[?1;2c2015-04-02 13:59:06     Messaging service successfully started.

2015-04-02 13:59:06     Starting balancer test port ...

2015-04-02 13:59:06     Balancer test port successfully started.

Thanks in advance.

Joan.

Comment: I saw you created a separate question for issue #3. Thank you. Can you close this question if it has been answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This is the expected behaviour. The background thread is simply keeping up with the log events your application is putting in the queue. Note that with log4j2, async logging will flush the buffer if the queue is empty, so results are immediately visible on disk. (See the docs for [FileAppender immediateFlush](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender).)
2. You may need to add the log4j-web module to your deployment. This is necessary to clean up log4j resources in a web application, and will also disable the shutdown hook. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html
3. This one is trickier... Can you provide your full log4j2 config? Any chance there are 2 processes writing to the same file?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Remko. Regarding point 2, now it seems to work fine, but this message appears when shutting down Tomcat (maybe it's normal): SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [AsyncLoggerConfig-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Regarding point 3, here it is a link to my log4j.xml: http://www.ventusproxy.com/download/log4j.xml. And no, when my app starts only the same (and only) thread is writing to the log.

Comment: It seems that these strange characters only appear in the vproxy_system log (SYSTEM_LOG appender).

Comment: Sorry, another thing... With log4j I could name my target log file with the current date. I mean, if today is 2015-04-04, the log file for today is vproxy.2015-04-04. At 00:00, a new file is created with name vproxy.2015-04-05 and my app starts to log on it. But it seems this is not possible with log4j2. Am I wrong?

Comment: You may need two $$ characters in the date lookup in the fileName attribute value: `fileName="${sys:log.dir}vproxy_access.$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}" `

Comment: I already tried it, and it created a file with name 'vproxy_access.${date:yyyy-MM-dd}'.

Comment: Ok, another option is to set a custom system property in the configuration: `<Properties><Property name="today">${date:yyyy-MM-dd}</property></Properties>` and then use this property in the file name `fileName="${sys:log.dir}vproxy_access.${sys:today}"`.

Comment: J, are all your issues resolved now, or only 1 and 2?

Comment: R, just 1 and 2. I've had to move back to log4j. This weekend I will try again with your suggestion (last comment about the date in log file name). Another issue I have to resolve is how to hide some apps to log, for example dwr. With log4j I achieved this by using: <logger name="uk.ltd.getahead.dwr"><level value="fatal"/></logger>. With log4j2 I tried <Logger name="uk.ltd.getahead.dwr" level="off" additivity="false"/> but it didin't work. So my issues are now: 1. Strange characters in log, 2. Date in log file name (pending to test your last suggestion), 3. Hide some apps to log.

Comment: Small adjustment for #2: I am doing this in a work project and the exact syntax needs two $ characters: `<properties<property name="logfile">logdir/logfile$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log</property></properties>` and in the file name I use `fileName="${sys:logfile}"`.

Comment: For #3, I think you are doing the right thing: to filter out log events produced by a specific logger in your code, you can configure a named logger with a matching name with a very strict level. `<Logger name="uk.ltd.getahead.dwr" level="off" additivity="false"/>` should result in log events generated by the logger `LogManager.getLogger("uk.ltd.getahead.dwr")` to not appear in the log file. Same for `LogManager.getLogger("uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.SomeClass")`.

Comment: thanks fo your time Remko. I'll try #2 and #3 again this weekend.

Comment: I think the mistery with point 2 is resolved. If I set the date pattern in both filename and filepattern, the file logyyyyMMdd (today date) is created, but when log4j tries to rotate at 00:00 it can't (probably because this file already exists). if filename is just "log", then it works. And that kills me, because all my algorithms need the date in the log names (even in the current log). This works with log4j1.2.17. Is a bug? Any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I can manage recoding my app to get info from the current log without date in the file name. At the same time, point 3 is solved by adding the log4j-jcl-2.2.jar to the WEB-INF/lib of the app that uses dwr. At this point only the strange chars in my system log is an issue. It seems that these chars only appear in the system log. Do you have any notice about someone with a similar issue? Thanks.

Comment: No, yours is the first report of this behaviour, I've never seen these characters or this kind of behaviour before. If you cannot close the question because of this remaining issue I suggest creating a separate question for this.

Comment: Ok R. Let me play a bit more with this. If I'm not able to sorti it out I will open another separate post. Thanks.